# how to avoid onchange on api call in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I have code in which I am using the select option. on change of option, I am submitting an API request which is to send data to the server.  when I load component I select option which are already selected for that onmount component i sending api request and assigning already selected values to variable `selected`. Now the problem is when i assign the values to select options select detect that value are changed so it submit request on page load. which is not needed it should only send request when user change options

this is select html

```
<ion-select interface="popover" multiple="true" v-model="selected" :value="selected" style="min-height: 90px;white-space: normal;" @ionChange="submitWorkerArrival()">
          <ion-select-option v-for="(worker, index) in workers" :key="index" v-bind:value="worker.id">{{worker.name}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

This is the get request in which i am assigning value to `selected` variable

```
ApiService.get(url).then((response) => {
          this.workers = response.data.workers;
          this.selected = Object.values([...new Set(response.data.arrived_workers)]);
        });
```

This is submit request which is I sumbit on change

```
 submitWorkerArrival() {

     
          ApiService.post(url, data).then(async (res) => {
})
}
```

Comment: could do a `watch` on `worker.id`

Answer (score 0):

I would add a watch to `selected`, this way when selection changes you are able to add additional logic based off of the previous state of the `selected` variable.

For example if `selected` was null but now it is not, you know that your code has loaded the previous value in, therefore there is no need to send a request to your API.

```js
watch:{
   selected:{
     handler(newVal, oldVal)
     {
         if(!oldVal) return; //prevent first load from firing event
         //Replace prop with a property that would change
         if(newVal.prop !== oldVal.prop){ 
            this.submitWorkerArrival();
         }
     },
     deep: true //important to watch object for changes
   }
}
```

Then you would remove

```
@ionChange="submitWorkerArrival()"
```

Learn more about [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) here